# Error Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. when compile apk from cocos2dx project

Tags: c++, android-studio, compiler-errors, cocos2d-x, dex

I'm new with cocos2d-x. I've stuck in this error for two day, when I compile my project, this showed up : * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':FlappyBird:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/phoenix/ASP/FlappyBird/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/libs/builder-3.1.0-alpha08.jar
>    and failed to compile. please help me!